# Use UIScrollView With Xcode 4.6

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, storyboard

I'm using Storyboards, and I've created a UIScrollView and its outlet:

`.h`

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@end
```

`.m` : I synthesized scrollView, and on viewDidLoad i have

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 
[super viewDidLoad];
self.scrollView.delegate = self;

// Init an array with 3 images
subviewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"image1.jpg", @"image2.jpg", @"image3.jpg", nil];

for (int i = 0; i < [subviewArray count]; i++) {
    //We'll create a View object in every 'page' of our scrollView.
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[subviewArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
}

NSLog(@"%f", self.scrollView.frame.size.width);

//Set the content size of our scrollview according to the total width of our imageView objects.
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * [subviewArray count], self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
}
```

The problem is when i print the value of "self.scrollView.frame.size.width" i get "0" !
Any help plz !!!

Comment: Did you connect the scroll view to the outlet? Is self.scrollView nil?

Comment: sure i did, when i don't use storyboard it works using the same logic !

Comment: And you verified that the instance is actually set at runtime?

Comment: I should also ask how you're creating the view controller from the storyboard.

Comment: Yes, the instance is set on run time

Comment: The ViewConroller is created on the storyboard !

Comment: Fix it, i had to uncheck "use AutoLayout" in file inspector. Thanks a lot Wain !
Hope this could help anyone else.
Good luck !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix it, i had to uncheck "use AutoLayout" in file inspector. Thanks a lot Wain ! Hope this could help anyone else. Good luck !